# How do you email a query result as a csv using sp_send_dbmail stored procedure with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, stored-procedures

I would like to send an email containing the results of a query as a csv attachment.

So far I have this;

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients='me@myself.com',
    @subject='CSV Extract', 
    @profile_name = 'Valid profile',
    @body='See attachment',
    @query ='SELECT TOP 10 c.* FROM MyDb.dbo.Customers c',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_Extract.csv',
    @query_result_separator = ','
```

I receive the email with a csv attachment but when opened in Excel the results are horribly formatted (e.g. all values are in a single column with seemingly random indentation)

What should I be doing to get a correctly formatted result with correct column headers etc?

**EDIT**

I have added the following parameters to the query;

```
@query_result_width = 32767,
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

This improved things a lot however I am still getting each record in a single column when opened inside Excel. How can I place each value within a record into it's own column?

This is what I currently get;

[image]

This is what I'm after;

[image]

Comment: since the formatting you need ,is known only to you,try playing with below values `@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =32767,
@query_result_no_padding=1`

Comment: Including "set nocount on;" in the query string got rid of the "(2 rows affected)" row in my results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Excel doesn't understand the columns. To fix this you need to send instructions to Excel explaining the csv file.

The instruction needs to be the first part of the file, before the data so you have to create an alias for the first field in the query that contains the Excel instructions along with the actual name you want

The instruction is “sep=,”, to ensure that excel will understand comma field separator.

```
DECLARE @column1name varchar(50)

-- Create the column name with the instrucation in a variable
SET @Column1Name = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Name]'
DECLARE @qry varchar(8000)

-- Create the query, concatenating the column name as an alias
SELECT @qry='set nocount on; SELECT TOP 10 c.CCustName ' + @column1name + 
         ' ,c.CID Id FROM MyDb.dbo.Customers c'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients='me@myself.com',
    @subject='CSV Extract', 
    @profile_name = 'Valid Profile',
    @body='See attachment',
    @query =@qry,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_Extract.csv',
    @query_result_separator = ',',
    @query_result_width = 32767,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1
```

These are the final results;

[image]

It's not perfect (Line two is annoying) but it is certainly good enough for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

Can also use
@query_result_separator = '    ',

Tab Delimiter

replacing the @query_result_separator = ',',

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).